# Emailing a comment from comment_area

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, email, heroku

I'm currently building a website with Ruby on Rails deployed with Heroku. I have a form on a comments and suggestions page that accepts a user email and suggestions on the website.

My question is how do I implement a way for the suggestions to be emailed to my website's email address after the user has submitted the suggestions?

Do I have to purchase a third party email server? Do I have to store the comments onto my DataBase?

Sorry if this seems obvious, I just started web development and appreciate all the help I can get!

Comment: Take a look at: http://railscasts.com/episodes/61-sending-email-revised for a nice little tutorial

Comment: is the older version outdated? i'm a student and is it worth the $9?

Answer (score 1):

I think the simpler way is to have a controller with a create action which create a record in the database and send an email.

You must to have a `Comment` model, a `CommentsController` and a form in your view. To send and email, you can follow [this guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html).

Welcome to Rails!

Comment: I was just about to post that same guide link :)! I think it's a great place to start for sending emails with Rails.

Comment: Could you elaborate on the controller part? The guide is very informative in terms of sending a email. but for receiving... its a completely different story

Comment: I don't understand why do you want to receive emails in your case. You want to be notified when a user add a new comment. That's it? If it is, you can do something like `CommentMailer.notify_on_new_email(@comment).deliver`. You can read [the guide for controller](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Heroku uses a service called SendGrid for sending emails. They have a developer subscription that let's you send a limited number of emails for free.

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/sendgrid